# Foreign key that doesn't point to a primary key in rails and postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Rails with a legacy postgres database, meaning no migrations. The schema is defined separately.

I have two tables: `notification` and `notification_type`. The `notification_type` table has an `ID` (primary key) and a `code` column. The `notification` table has a `notitification_type` column with a foreign key on the `notificiation_type` table's `code` column.

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :notification_type, foreign_key: 'notification_type'
  ...
```

NotificationType:

```
class NotificationType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
end
```

When I call create on the notification model, it gives me a foreign key error because it's trying to create with the ID column of notification_type, not the code column.

> ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "notification" violates foreign key constraint "notification_notification_type_fkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (notification_type)=(18) is not present in table "notification_type".

Where 18 is the ID, but I need it to use the code, which would be something like 1 or 2. I saw the `association_foreign_key` value, but it seems that it only works with the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

psql, just for closure:

> Foreign-key constraints:
>       "notification_notification_type_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (notification_type) REFERENCES notification_type(code)

Basically, how do I get rails to honor the foreign key relationships in my database instead of always using the primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
belongs_to :notification_type, foreign_key: 'notification_type', primary_key: 'code'
```

The `primary_key` defaults to `id` but you can use anything you want.

You'll want to specify the same options for your `has_many :notifications` association - the has_many is completely unaware of it's associated belongs_to, so it needs to know if you're using non-standard keys as well.

Comment: I swear I tried this already. I could have sworn, anyway. I tried again and it works. I must have mixed something up somewhere; thank you so much!